# Why CFX Interceptor not working in spring-boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cxf, interceptor

**What I want to do**

I need to write something in Database using CFX InInterceptor in Spring-boot application.

**I'm using :**

name: 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.6.RELEASE'

name: 'cxf-spring-boot-starter-jaxrs', version: '3.3.5'

**here is CfxConfig.java**

```
package com.test.config;


import ....;


@Configuration
public class CfxConfig {

    HeaderInterceptor headerInterceptor;

    @Autowired
    public CfxConfig(HeaderInterceptor headerInterceptor){
        this.headerInterceptor = headerInterceptor;
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean<CXFServlet> dispatcherServlet() {
        return new ServletRegistrationBean<CXFServlet>(new CXFServlet(), "/es-services/ws/*");
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DispatcherServletPath dispatcherServletPathProvider() {
        return () -> "";
    }


    @Bean
    public Endpoint endpoint(Bus bus, CentralSystemServiceEndpoint ocppCentralService) {
        EndpointImpl endpoint = new EndpointImpl(bus, ocppCentralService, SOAPBinding.SOAP12HTTP_BINDING);
        endpoint.publish("/service1");
        endpoint.getBus().getInInterceptors().add(this.headerInterceptor);
        return endpoint;
    }

}
```

**here is HeaderInterceptor.java**

```
package com.test.ws.interceptor;

import ....;

@Slf4j
@Service
public class HeaderInterceptor extends AbstractPhaseInterceptor<Message> {

    private InboundXmlPayloadDao inboundXmlPayloadDao;

    @Autowired
    public HeaderInterceptor(InboundXmlPayloadDao inboundXmlPayloadDao) {
        super(Phase.PRE_PROTOCOL);
        this.inboundXmlPayloadDao = inboundXmlPayloadDao;
    }

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message message) throws Fault {
        String ip = CentralSystemServiceImpl.getRemoteIP();
        String uuid = CentralSystemServiceImpl.getUuid();
        String soapXmlPayload = CentralSystemServiceImpl.getPayload();

        log.info(String.format("IP: %s Message: %s", ip, soapXmlPayload));
        inboundXmlPayloadDao.save(new InboundXmlPayload(uuid, soapXmlPayload, ip));
    }

}
```

Everything is working, SOAP server is working, all response are perfectly working, but it newer call interceptor.

### when I'm checking [In Evaluate Expression](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCLBX.png)

What is interesting, if I'm disable all Autowired fields in "HeaderInterceptor.java" and add interceptor directly like this:

```
endpoint.getBus().getInInterceptors().add(new HeaderInterceptor());
```

everything is working, and the interceptor is working as supposed. Only problem interaction with database  :(

---

**Any idea about this strange behavior?**